# Are overdispersion and underdispersion in a binomial logistic regression model an issue if the model is not being used to make predictions?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, glmm, overdispersion, underdispersion

If a binomial logistic regression model is being used strictly to identify variables that have an impact on the dependent variable but is not being used to make predictions, are underdispersion and over dispersion still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it certainly is an issue.  If you use hypothesis tests on the coefficients, and there is overdispersion, but you don't account for it: Some coefficients might be significantly different from zero, just because standard errors are estimated to small (and confidence intervals too short).

In the same way, with underdispersion, the opposite occurs, some coefficients might be falsely non-significant, because standard errors are estimated to large. And confidence intervals too long.